# How do we on SO define a specific programming problem?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

Today, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931156/algorithm-interview) which has been closed as off-topic for the reason:

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming within the scope [defined by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about reopening questions here. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

Now, if you *follow* that link, it appears that the question could quite easily fit into *three* of the positive categories, "a specific programming problem", "a software algorithm" and "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

It also appears not to be otherwise covered by any of the six exceptions, although I guess a case *could* be made that interview questions are similar to homework and no indication was given in the original question as to what effort had been made (I tend to assume in those cases, when answering, that the poster has no idea so simply provide guidance).

In any case, I edited the question to the best of my abilities to indicate the OP had no idea how to approach the problem but it appears to me that even the *original* question was a valid one, based on the guidelines given.

So what is it about this question that makes it unsuitable for SO (if that is indeed the consensus view)? Are we to disallow interview questions like we used to with homework?

Comment: Hmya, interview questions...  You are supposed to explain out how to pass the interview and get hired.  Using 4 gigabytes of VM probably does not, even though it is readily available and might well give you an edge for out-of-the-box thinking ;0  And the way it is always done on an IBM machine.  You have to sell it.

Comment: Edit out the "I went to an interview today and was asked this question:".  Now what do you think about the question?  I think we need more information about the asker's environment if the asker cares about practical performance, or else if they want the best big-O regardless of constants, or if they want an analysis in the ideal cache model, or..., but I can see someone else feeling a generic answer is worth writing.

Comment: The question in question *might* fair better over on [codegolf.se], but I'd look at their [help center](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first...

Answer (score 3):

The poster of the question says:

> I'm not even sure where I would start on this question

So the poster lacks so much knowledge that they have *no idea* how to even try to create a solution. Any attempt to provide a solution would have to educate them on several topics they do not understand. Not a *specific* topic. So there is no specific question here.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, if you follow that link, it appears that the question could quite
>   easily fit into three of the positive categories, "a specific
>   programming problem", "a software algorithm" and "a practical,
>   answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Above question fits into those aspects. But it is closed as off-topic because it is *give me the code* question. Or *give me the algorithm* (same thing). I would say that more appropriate close vote for above question would be "Too broad".

OP didn't show any effort in solving that problem himself and that is covered by "This question does not show any research effort..." tooltip for down voting.

Also help center page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page says:

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
>   you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it.

Interview question or homework question makes no big difference.

If poster has code that does not work he can ask question on Stack Overflow. If he has code that works but he want's to improve it he can post it on Code Review.

---

On the other hand answer(s) to such question, even though question itself is poor and shows no effort, can be valuable resource and is on-topic. But it does not automatically transform poor question into a good one.

Comment: Technically, down-voting and close-voting are two different things, so it doesn't make sense to apply the voting tooltips for close-votes.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Technically you are correct, but those two are related. This kind of question asked today would attract both close and down votes. I think both aspects are relevant.

Comment: As a side note, my personal voting policy on such questions is. I don't down vote them (especially, if they were asked a long ago) but I don't up vote them either. I do up vote answers if I find them (personally) useful.

Comment: Why should the decision to downvote have anything to do with the age of the question?

Comment: @CodyGray Because at one point such question might have been on-topic.

Comment: I would say the main difference between homework and an interview question is that the interview questions are almost certainly in the past. You don't tend to leave an interview and come back a week later with an answer. Or at least you don't unless the interviewer is a complete bonehead :-) In any case, if the rule applies to interview questions as well, I'd suggest that be spelled out in the help page. Otherwise it's just an assumption on the part of the reader. As an aside, how do you treat questions where the OP doesn't even *know* where to start?

Comment: @paxdiablo __I don't know where to start.__ If you really don't know where to start, then frankly, you should not be doing interviews at all. And if you have beginner asking such question, it is a bit harder to say what to do. Tell them to divide problem in steps and try do solve each step independently. But, this also depends on the question. But nonetheless such __I don't know what to do__ questions are currently off-topic.

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually, now when I think of it, more appropriate close vote would be "Too broad".